# Is there a way to simply resemble a truth table?

Tags: c#

Is there any simple way to resemble a truth table in code? It has 2 inputs and 4 outcomes, as shown below:

[image]

My current code is:

```
private void myMethod(bool param1, bool param2)
{
    Func<int, int, bool> myFunc;
    if (param1)
    {
        if (param2)
            myFunc = (x, y) => x >= y;
        else
            myFunc = (x, y) => x <= y;
    }
    else
    {
        if (param2)
            myFunc = (x, y) => x < y;
        else
            myFunc = (x, y) => x > y;
    }
    //do more stuff
}
```

Comment: It's called "truth table".

Comment: You might want to look up the term `state machine` as it seems you are heading towards that direction.

Comment: what is wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Typo, I will correct it. Thanks

Comment: This is not a truth table. The output of a truth table is a boolean, not a function.

Comment: And by the way, your code looks easily readable. Do not over complicate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using an *array*, i.e.

```
  // XOR truth table
  bool[][] truthTable = new bool[][] {
    new bool[] {false, true},
    new bool[] {true, false},
  };
```

...

```
  private void myMethod(bool param1, bool param2, bool[][] table) {
    return table[param1 ? 0 : 1][param2 ? 0 : 1];
  }
```

Comment: You can't index arrays with `bool`s

Comment: @Lee: thank you, I see (`C#` is not a `C`), ternaty operator is required

Answer (score 0):

```
public int myTest(bool a, bool b)
{
  if(!b)
    return 3;
  return a ? 1 : 2;
}
```

Comment: I believe that OP is looking for a more generic solution

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code you could use `param1` and `param2` as bits of a value indexing in a predefined array:

```
private void myMethod(bool param1, bool param2)
{
    Func<int, int, bool>[] myFuncs = {
        (x, y) => x > y,
        (x, y) => x < y,
        (x, y) => x <= y,
        (x, y) => x >= y
    };

    int index = (param1 ? 2 : 0) + (param2 ? 1 : 0);
    Func<int, int, bool> myFunc = myFuncs[index];
    //do more stuff
}
```

But of course simplicity and readability is in the eye of the reader.

If both `paramX` are `false`, `index` will be `0`. If both are `true`, `index` will be `3` etc...